# If we want to write a function in power series, what's the first n? 0 or 1?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

So, for instance $e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, why do we start from n=0, and not n=1? Why do we care about some zero$^{th}$ term? Do we do the same with other functions? Why?

Comment: The zeroth term contributes to the sum. If the sum started with $n=1$, it would not be correct.

Comment: The term with zero *index* is not necessarily zero in *value*, as this case illustrates. Of course it counts.

Comment: Hum, I see. Sorry for the stupid question, but why can't we start from n=(-1) or n=(-2)? I think the answer to the question should help me understand why do we set these boundaries. I think I just don't understand something fundamentally.

Comment: Some basic sanity checks: If you omit the $n=0$ term and evaluate both sides at $x=0$, the left hand side is $e^0 = 1$ but the right hand side is $0$. If you start the series at $n=-1$ or $n=-2$ then (assuming you can make sense of $n!$ for negative $n$), the right hand side blows up at $x=0$ but the left hand side does not.

Comment: @Bungo, oh, that makes sense. About -1 and -2 and factorials, I didn't necessarily mean this exact function.

Comment: But I mean yes, the term with zero index isn't always zero, but conceptually — what is the zeroth term? And I must say I like the "sanity check", meaning we should try to see if 0 in index makes more sense, because in the end that's our end goal — to express the function in series form. PS: I know this sort of thing sometimes happens in evaluating a definite integral, from 0 to some A. Where sometimes indefinite integral at zero is not really zero (e.g. cos(x)), so curiously we have to subtract this ind. integral at 0 from ind. integral at A.

Comment: Oh, and I also forgot that if the geometric series on which we base our power series, would start from 1 and not 0, then the convergence formula would look different than 1/(1-x). And that's why we should start our power series at 0, and then maybe drop the 0 and start from 1 if at n=0 the term evaluates to 0. But even still zeroth term is a bit of a curious concept to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,$$

and that this is valid on an interval containing $0$, then

$$f(0)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n0^n=a_0.$$

So the constant term $a_0$ is the value of the function at $0$.  If all of our power series started with $n=1$, say

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n,$$

then $f(0)=0$ all the time.

Comment: So basically just ensuring we do add enough terms to justify the equality sign?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly look at it that way.

Answer (score 0):

When referring specifically to taylor series, we have (if $f$ is analytic near $a$)
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(a)\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}
$$
where the zeroth derivative is $f$ itself ($f^{(0)}:=f$).  So in this case, we typically start with $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$ $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$ Which one is equal to the power series of $e^x$ ?